# WPF: ListView Cannot Get Focus when Click in Blank Area

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

ListView can only get focus when clicking on listview items. When clicking on blank area, which is also part of the listview, focus cannot be got.

Example:

```
      <Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="lv" 
                      GotFocus="Lv_OnGotFocus"
                      LostFocus="Lv_OnLostFocus"
                      MouseEnter="Lv_OnMouseEnter">
                <ListViewItem>Foo</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Bar</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
```

[image: Mouse Move In Area]

In code above I bind event handler to the listview not the listview item.

- When cursor moves in the blank area, *Lv_OnMouseEnter* handler is triggered, which indicate the blank area are also part of listview.
- When clicking in the blank area, *Lv_OnGotFocus* is not triggered. Focus not got.
- When clicking on any listview item, *Lv_OnGotFocus* is triggered. Focus got.
- It's even the SAME, when *Lv_OnGotFocus* handler was moved to outter **Grid**.

How to get focus when any part of listview is clicked ?

> WHY I need focus on blank area?
>
> I'm implementing file Copy & Paste function in the listview, in which listview items bind to files on disk. Paste action is triggered by a *PreviewKeyDown* handler attached to the listview, in which *Ctrl + V* key press is checked.
>
> If a folder is empty, the listview is empty. Thus *PreviewKeyDown* handler cannot be triggered , as the *Lv_OnGotFocus* handler, in a empty folder,  Whereas copying file into empty folder meant to be work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy workaround is to handle clicks:

```
<ListView PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ... />
```

to set focus

```
void ListView_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) =>
    (sender as ListBox)?.Focus();
```

Note: this will cause `GotFocus` to be called twice when clicking on normal items.

Comment: It works for me, though it does not explain why ListView cannot get focus via clicking automatically.